# ListView With MultipleChoice CheckBox selection Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am implementing a multiplechoice checkbox.  I have successfully populated the listview with the chexbox item using

```
DestinataireAdapter destinataireAdapter = new DestinataireAdapter(m, destinataire);
mylist.setAdapter(destinataireAdapter);
destinataireAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is my DestinataireAdapter class:

```
public class DestinataireAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<Destinataire> data;

    public DestinataireAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Destinataire> products) {
        ctx = context;
        data = products;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.destinataire_item, parent, false);
        }

        Destinataire pos = getselectedposition(position);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txDestinataireItem)).setText(data.get(position).getNickName());
        CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
        chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
        chkbox.setTag(position);
        chkbox.setChecked(pos.ischeckedflag);
        return view;
    }

    Destinataire getselectedposition(int position) {
        return ((Destinataire) getItem(position));
    }

    public ArrayList<Destinataire> getcheckedposition() {
        ArrayList<Destinataire> checkedposition = new ArrayList<Destinataire>();
        for (Destinataire p : data) {
            if (p.ischeckedflag)
                checkedposition.add(p);
        }
        return checkedposition;
    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            getselectedposition((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).ischeckedflag = isChecked;
        }
    };
}
```

for example i select multiple item on the menu and click on a button to get all position checked from the listview. I use the method below

```
public void GetSelectedPositions(View v) {
    String result = "Selected Position is";
    // result += "\n" + p.position;
    for (Destinataire p : destinataireAdapter.getcheckedposition()) {
        if (p.ischeckedflag){
            // int pp= p.position;
            result += "," + p.position;

            System.out.println(p.position);



        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, result, 500).show();
}
```

and the Destinataire class model where values of id,version, and nickName are stored.

```
public class Destinataire {



    String id;
    String version;
    String nickName;

    public int  position;   
    public boolean ischeckedflag;

    public Destinataire(String id, String version, String nickName){


        this.id=id;
        this.version=version;
        this.nickName=nickName;

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }




    Destinataire(int name, boolean flag) {

        position = name;       
        ischeckedflag = flag;
    }

}
```

When the toast appears i get result 0,0,0 for the choice i made instead of the ids populated from Destinataire class.  How can i get the corresponding id when i made choices. any help please.

Answer (score 2):

http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-multiple-select-listview.html

This above link may be helpful to you